# SQL Selecting "Window" Around Particular Row

Tags: sql, mysql

It's quite possible a question like this has been asked before, but I can't think of the terms to search for.

I'm working on a photo gallery application, and want to display 9 thumbnails showing the context of the current photo being shown (in a 3x3 grid with the current photo in the centre, unless the current photo is in the first 4 photos being shown, in which case if e.g. if the current photo is the 2nd I want to select photos 1 through 9). For example, given an album containing the list of photos with ids:

1, 5, 9, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26

If the current photo is 19, I want to also view:

9, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23

If the current photo is 5, I want to also view:

1, 5, 9, 12, 13, 18, 19, 20, 21

I've been thinking of something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM photos
WHERE ABS(id - currentphoto) < 5
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 25
```

but this doesn't work in the case where the ids are non-sequential (as in the example above), or for the case where there are insufficient photos before the currentphoto.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Dom

p.s. Please leave a comment if anything is unclear, and I'll clarify the question. If anyone can think of a more useful title to help other people find this question in future, then please comment too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably could just use a UNION, and then trim off the extra results in the procedural code that displays the results (as this will return 20 rows in the non-edge cases):

```
(SELECT 
     * 
FROM photos
   WHERE ID < #current_id#
   ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
  (SELECT *
   FROM photos
   WHERE ID >= #current_id#
   ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 10)
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

EDIT: Increased limit to 10 on both sides of the UNION, as suggested by **le dorfier**.

EDIT 2: Modified to better reflect final implementation, as suggested by Dominic.

Comment: This is a good, useful technique. I've used it with MySQL in the past. To handle the ends of the list, where you wouldn't have enough rows: use LIMIT 10 and work out the selection in the procedural code.

Comment: Thanks le dorfier, that solves the issue with the limits, I'll edit as suggested.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this. I added an "ORDER BY id ASC" on the result of the UNION, so the rows came back as intended. You'll need to change the first ORDER to be by id DESC, otherwise the first few rows will always come back.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server, you can use the row_number() function to give you the row order index and do something like this:

```
declare @selected_photo integer;
set @selected_photo = 5;

declare @buffer_size integer;
set @buffer_size = 2;

select
   ph.rownum,
   ph.id
from
   (select row_number() over (order by Id) as rownum, * from Photos) as ph
where
   ph.rownum between case
                         when @selected_photo - @buffer_size < 1 then 1
                         else @selected_photo - @buffer_size
                      end
                      and @selected_photo + @buffer_size
```

Edit:
Here is an article on simulating the row_number() function in MySQL, combining that with
this might get you what you need - I'd try it but don't have a MySQL db handy to play with at work. :-)

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks Ron - but I'm using MySQL, so I don't think I can use this - can I?

Comment: I don't see anything similar in the MySQL docs ... but I'll keep poking around. :-)

Comment: @RonSavage: don't bother. MySQL is one of the few DBMS left that don't support windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard "Row ordering" problem... If your database has rowId capability you can use that, otherwise you need a subquery that counts the numnber of rows with Ids less than the id of the current row... like this:

-- asssuming @Id is value of id in the "middle"

```
 Select *  From Photos P
 Where (Select Count(*) From Photos
         Where id <= P.Id)
     Between (Select Count(*) From Photos
              Where id < @Id) - 4
        And  (Select Count(*) From Photos
              Where id < @Id) + 4
```

As a comment raised the album issue you would want to add album predicate to each subquery

```
   Select *  From Photos P
   Where (Select Count(*) From Photos
          Where album = @album
            And id <= P.Id)
     Between (Select Case When Count(*) < 4 
                      Then 4 Else Count(*) End
              From Photos
              Where album = @album
                 And id < @Id) - 4
        And  (Select Case When Count(*) < 4 
                      Then 4 Else Count(*) End
              From Photos
              Where album = @album
                  And id < @Id) + 4
```

Comment: There should be additional filter by album, otherwise it does not solve the the problem - i.e. it will work on sequential id only.